# How to find possible problems with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, code-analysis

I need a tool watching for a running Java application and reporting about incorrect use of Swing GUI library in it. It should be easy to find places where methods like setVisible() are invoked from a non UI thread for example.

Integration with IntelliJ IDEA is a plus.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it from a running application but there are code coverage tools where you can add such rules and catch the problem before the program is even executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Substance Look&Feel](https://substance.dev.java.net/), it has runtime checks for EDT violations, see [this page](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/07/15/stricter-checks-on-edt-violations-in-substance.html) for details.

Comment: A smart way for UI debugging :) Thank you!